# Using Partial View and Jquery to enable selection from the same dropdownlist in different Views

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have the following dropdownlist to filter the results based on the selected Course. The following div is copied to 5 different views, since in all of these views I need to filter some data based on the selected Course from the dropdownlist.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
        @Html.DropDownList("Courses", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="btn btn-info filterbycourse"> FILTER</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In each of these views, I have the following script which sets the action url. The following code has `Badge` as the controller. However, the controller is different in the other 4 views. So, only the `controller` name changes in the script across the views.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".filterbycourse").click(function () {
            var course_id = $('#Courses').val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Badge", new { CourseId = "----" }, null)';
            url = url.replace("----", course_id);
            window.location = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I know I can create a partial view for this. However, I will still need to have the jQuery script in all the views that uses the partial view. I wonder if there is an effective way of dealing with this situation?

Comment: In your `<a>` element, add `data-url="@Url.Action(....)"` and then in the script, get the url using `var url = $(this).data('url');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke then you do not recommend using a Partial View?

Comment: If you wanted to use a partial, then you could always pass a value to the partial indicating the controller name - `@Html.Partial("...", new { controller = "..."})` to build the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the dropdown in the partial view and use it. For the script which handles the click event, you need it to keep in only one place, but use different base url's for different pages.

So in your indidual views/pages which uses this partial, you have to set the base url like this

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
     var settings = settings || {};
     settings.SearchUrl="@Url.Action("Search","Badge", new { CourseId = "----" })";     
  </script>
}
```

and update your common script to read this value from the current page and use that to build the final url.

```
$(function () {
    $(".filterbycourse").click(function () {
        var course_id = $('#Courses').val();
        var baseUrl = settings.SearchUrl;
        var url = baseUrl ;
        url = url.replace("----", course_id);
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! So, the common script needs to go every View that uses the partial view right?

Comment: Yes. I would put it in your common script file / layout.